# Can I change wallet without shifting funds

Tags: multibit, private-key-export

I have some fund in Multibit, a wallet that has now become almost unusable. I do not want to risk transferring all my bitcoins to another non-Multibit wallet because my last transaction is still stuck in "sending" mode weeks after I sent some bitcoin.

So I am wondering if it is possible to sign up with another wallet provider and somehow recover my Multibit funds directly from the blockchain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, depending on what version of multibit you have, you can do the following :

- Multibit HD: You should have the backup seed words. You can directly use those seed words / [master public key](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1628298.0) to create a new wallet like mycelium/electrum
- Multibit Classic: Export out all the private keys https://multibit.org/help/v0.5/help_exportingPrivateKeys.html. You can import these private keys into the new wallet

Comment: Installed Electrum (Linux) and used restore option. Used my 12  Multibit HD words and created a new wallet. It is empty. Checked Multibit and the funds are still here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok correction. Seems like you ran into HD wallet compatibility issue due to different derviation paths. Check the mnemonic compatibility sheet here  https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1000544.0.  You can try with Mycelium.

Comment: I checked the link and it looks as if it is a work in progress. I will try Myceilium and report the result.

Let us suppose Multibit is not compromised but simply stops supporting its customers. What happens to the funds? Is blockchain network robust enough to allow wallet holders to recover their funds (in another wallet such as Mycelium) bypassing Multibit altogether?

Comment: Both multibit/mycelium is open source and not a website. They use SPV to interact with blockchain network

Comment: @darkknight: I think you may be able to answer this question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/54447/5406 Could you please take a look?

Comment: @Murch Thanks a lot for the mention. Caught up with something these days. Will try to answer as soon as I get time.